# SSH ports and recorded connection in auth.log

Tags: ssh

I have an SSH server configured to a port that is not the default one (let's say 2222).

Looking in `/var/log/auth.log` on that server, I see records of successful SSH connections that look like

```
Accepted publickey for <user> from <ip> port <number> ssh2: ....
```

However, `<number>` is never 2222. Instead, it is usually five digits, and seems to be different on each new login.

Consulting some references, like [this one](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Logging_and_Troubleshooting), this seems to be expected behavior in the sense that their examples of successful logins also have log records with ports that are some random-looking five digit number.

But I haven't been able to find an explanation of why this is. I would expect that the logins would be 2222. The question is why my expectation is wrong, and why the port that is recorded changes every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are seeing the source ports of the connection. It's the port that is used on the client, it's random and it's usually high. This is nothing special with SSH, you will see this with every service.

This is entirely normal.

Comment: I should have paid better attention to the specific wording of the logs: It clearly says *from* <ip> port <number>.